# How to get original command line from process with python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, psutil

```
import psutil

for p in psutil.process_iter():
    if p.name() == 'foo':
        print p.cmdline()
        print ' '.join(p.cmdline())
 
PROCESS:
   foo -p "Hello World"
RESULT:
   ['foo', '-p', 'Hello World']
   foo -p Hello World
```

I wish to get the original command line for a process as in `foo -p "Hello World"`, I've tried to use `cmdline()` but it provides parameters tokenized, which I'm not interested into, and joining them doesn't produce the expected result all the time, as can be seen from result's second print.

Is there a way to achieve this preferably in a portable way (maybe using other library or doing it differently)?

### EDIT

This is for sake of comparison with an already stored command. Another solution to my problem could be that just `' '.join` would be ok if I could get the static command string (`foo -p "Hello World"`) without the quotes that are around args to do the comparison. Meaning, if there were a function that did the shell param tokenization that psutil is doing, it would solve my command comparison problem.

Comment: @poolie mostly yes, but also, a solution that simply joins parameters that contains whitespace in them won't be optimal I guess, in more complex commands.

Comment: @Rogalski thanks, I guess that should do it.

Answer (score 0):

Using [shlex.quote](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shlex.html) will reassemble the array into a shell command line, writing spaces and other special characters.

Comment: No such method in python 2.7, I've tagged the question as such, just updated it.

Answer (score 0):

With some work you could use Lib/pipes in 2.7. https://docs.python.org/2/library/pipes.html

Comment: Thanks, I've accepted my question as a duplicate.